# 4 qubit QFT decomposition in the qiskit textbook

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, quantum-fourier-transform

I am reading about the quantum Fourier transform (QFT) in the [qiskit textbook](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/algorithms/phase-estimation#phase-29-0), but got stuck at the last part of it which shows a decomposed version of the 4 qubit QFT circuit.

[image]

It seems that the decomposition is a bit different than the QFT definition, in that the swap gates are placed differently. I guess some amount of simple optimizations for swap gates has been performed there in the decomposed version, but I can't figure out exactly what has happened. To me, the decomposition should look something like the following.

[image]

Can someone please explain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: On which resource do you base your decomposition on? In the QFT, the only SWAP gates are supposed to happen at the end of the circuit, but yours has some in the middle of it

Comment: @MarkSpinelli  I am following the little endian way of enumerating the qubits as the qiskit does.

Comment: @TristanNemoz The decomposition is based on the recursive implementation as described in the qiskit textbook, where swap gates are used at every recursive step. By the way, I recently figured out the qiskit decomposition of QFT4 is equivalent to the recursive definition -- qiskit is doing a little bit of optimization to reduce the swap gates in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

In Qiskit textbook<sup>[[1](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform)]</sup>, `qft` function is defined as follows:

```
def qft(circuit, n):
    """QFT on the first n qubits in circuit"""
    qft_rotations(circuit, n)
    swap_registers(circuit, n)
    return circuit
```

So, QFT circuit is created by calling two functions, `qft_rotations` and `swap_registers`. And while `qft_rotations` function is recursive, `swap_registers` is not. Which means SWAP gates will be added to the circuit only once.

This is the circuit described in most introductory texts to quantum computation.

In "Phase estimation and factoring"<sup>[[2](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/algorithms/phase-estimation)]</sup> tutorial, another quantum Fourier transform circuit is described. This other circuit, inspired by fast Fourier transform algorithm, is constructed recursively. You can find the details in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.quant-ph/0411069)

Due to its recursive nature, a layer of SWAP gates is added to permute the order of the qubits after each step. However, these SWAP gates can be pushed to the end of the circuit as stated clearly in the tutorial:

> We don't actually need as many swap gates as the method describes — if we rearrange the gates just a bit, we can push all of the swap gates out to the right [...]

Comment: The recursive circuit implementation of QFT I originally asked about is described [here](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/algorithms/phase-estimation#phase-29-0). The four steps of implementation is, 1. Apply the 2^(m-1) dim QFT to the leftmost qubits (little endian), 2. Inject phases 
for each standard basis state of the (m-1) qubits, 3. Perform a Hadamard gate on the rightmost qubit, 4. Shift the qubits so that the LSB becomes the MSB. The QFT5 implementation using this definition shows [here](https://learn.qiskit.org/content/v2/algorithms/03.phase-estimation/images/QFT_32.png)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. My question was about the second implementation in your description, and the confusing part was about the rearranging the gates to remove the swap gates in the middle, as drawn by qiskit's decompose() method. I somehow figured out how that happened and I am clear now. Thanks!